# Rijndael Encryption | Padding is invalid and cannot be removed

Tags: c#, encryption

Im new to cryptography and im not quite sure what im doing wrong here,

```
public static byte[] EncryptData(byte[] data, string keystr)
{
    if (keystr.Length > 32)
        keystr = keystr.Substring(0, 32);
    else
        while (keystr.Length != 32)
            keystr += "0";

    byte[] iv = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(SALT);
    byte[] key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(keystr);

    using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (RijndaelManaged rijndaelManaged = new RijndaelManaged { Key = key, IV = iv, Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7, Mode = CipherMode.CBC })
        {
            using (CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, rijndaelManaged.CreateEncryptor(key, iv), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                cryptoStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
            }
        }
        return memoryStream.ToArray();
    }
}

public static byte[] DecryptData(byte[] data, string keystr)
{
    if (keystr.Length > 32)
        keystr = keystr.Substring(0, 32);
    else
        while (keystr.Length != 32)
            keystr += "0";

    byte[] iv = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(SALT);
    byte[] key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(keystr.ToUpper());

    using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (RijndaelManaged rijndaelManaged = new RijndaelManaged { Key = key, IV = iv, Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7, Mode = CipherMode.CBC })
        {
            using (CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, rijndaelManaged.CreateDecryptor(key, iv), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                cryptoStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
            }
        }
        return memoryStream.ToArray();
    }
}
```

As you can see im passing in a byte array and a password. i make sure the password is always 32 chars.

Im getting `Padding is invalid and cannot be removed.` when i decrypt data.

The key and salt is always the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `key` may be passed in the same to both methods, but for some reason, after you've thrown away more entropy (for longer strings) or padded out the key (for shorter strings), for some reason you do this:

```
keystr.ToUpper()
```

But only for the decryption side. So the keys being used are different.

I'd strongly suggest that you don't call `ToUpper`. Other suggestions would be to probably not have a fixed salt/IV and to allow both the iv and the key to be passed as byte arrays also, rather than `strings`. Encryption naturally deals with byte arrays, and putting wrapper methods like these in place that actually encourage weaker encryption is probably a bad idea.

Comment: Ahh thanks a lot, stupid copy paste error from my previous encryption class.